# How to get the route from UrlRule in yii/craft cms

Tags: php, yii, craftcms

I have route in my routes.php file and I also have routes in my module like so:

```
return [
  'analytics/<tenantSlug:{slug}>/modules/' => ['route' => 'analytics/modules/list', 'name' => 'listModules']
];
```

and

```
private function attachEventHandlers(): void
{
    Event::on(
        UrlManager::class,
        UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
        function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
            $event->rules['analytics/<tenantSlug:{slug}>/modules/'] = ['route' => 'analytics/modules/list', 'name' => 'listModules'];
        });
}
```

I'm trying to create a plugin which gets urls by name

to get the urls from the routes.php file is simple I just need to do this:

```
$routes = Craft::$app->getRoutes()->getConfigFileRoutes();
foreach ($routes as $route => $route_settings) {
    return $route;
}
```

this will return

```
'analytics/<tenantSlug:{slug}>/modules/'
```

to get the module urls I have to do this:

```
return Craft::dd(Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->rules[0]);
```

which gives me this:

```
craft\web\UrlRule#1
(
    [name] => 'listModules'
    [pattern] => '#^analytics/(?P<ac53bbfc2>(?:[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{M}\\._\\-]+))/modules$#u'
    [host] => null
    [route] => 'analytics/modules/list'
    [defaults] => []
    [suffix] => null
    [verb] => null
    [mode] => null
    [encodeParams] => true
    [normalizer] => null
    [*:createStatus] => null
    [*:placeholders] => [
        'ac53bbfc2' => 'tenantSlug'
    ]
    [yii\web\UrlRule:_template] => '/analytics/<tenantSlug>/modules/'
    [yii\web\UrlRule:_routeRule] => null
    [yii\web\UrlRule:_paramRules] => [
        'tenantSlug' => '#^(?:[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{M}\\._\\-]+)$#u'
    ]
    [yii\web\UrlRule:_routeParams] => []
    [params] => []
)
```

I don't know how to get a usable route from that. I need it in the same format as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Needed to dig through the code because I find the documentation lacking

```
        $manager = Craft::$app->getUrlManager();
        $rules = Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->rules;
        foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            if(isset($rule->$keyword) && $rule->$keyword == $route_name){
                $selected_route = $rule->createUrl($manager, $rule->route, $provided_tokens);
            }
        }
```